# Why the Binary_Cross-entropy Loss is giving negative values?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am running this model for 1080 training images and 270 validation set. This model is for skin lesion segmentation and data is from ISIC 2016.

I don't understand Why the Binary_Cross-entropy Loss is giving negative values, this is my first model.

I went through many answers but can't understand any, I mean where I should do changes

Here's my code-

```
def segnet(epochs_num,savename):

# Encoding layer
img_input = Input(shape= (320,320, 3))
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv1',strides= (1,1)) 
(img_input)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn1')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn2')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)

x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv3')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn3')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv4')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn4')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)

x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv5')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn5')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv6')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn6')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv7')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn7')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)

x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv8')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn8')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv9')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn9')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv10')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn10')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)


x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu', name='fc3')(x)
# Decoding Layer 
x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv1')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn14')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn15')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv3')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn16')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)


x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv7')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn20')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv8')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn21')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv9')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn22')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv10')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn23')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv11')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn24')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv12')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn25')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv13')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn26')(x)
x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)



pred = Reshape((320,320))(x)

model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=pred)

model.compile(optimizer= Adam(lr=0.001, decay=0.0005) ,loss= 
['binary_crossentropy' ] , metrics=[iou, dice_coef, precision, recall, 
accuracy])


model.summary()
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs= epochs_num, batch_size= 10, 
validation_data= (x_val, y_val), verbose=1)
#hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs= epochs_num, batch_size= 10, 
validation_data= (x_val, y_val))

#hist=model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs_num, batch_size=10)
model.save(savename)
return model,hist'''
```

[image]

Comment: BCE would give negative loss if your labels are not in the [0, 1] range.

Comment: Please copy & paste the model history here as *text*, not an image.

Comment: So how to change labels and how would i know their range?

Comment: How can we tell you how to change the labels what we don't know how they currently are?

Comment: Okay So I got that the pixel values in the training dataset (Ground Truth) has values ranging 0 to 255 while it should be labelled as 0 or 1 only and I guess thats only causing BCE to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

So, the mistake was, I didn't made the images Binary Images before, basically didn't labelled the image pixels as 0/1 and then results were pretty good.

[image: These are results]